# php simple session not working with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

```
// Read Get cerruncy from URL request
if(in_array("crncy",$get_page_all)) {
$crnc_set = explode("/crncy/",$open_page);
$crnc = $crnc_set[1];
$get_crnc = (string) $crnc;
$_SESSION['xxxc'] = $get_crnc;
}
if($_SESSION['xxxc']){
echo $_SESSION['xxxc'];
}
else {echo 'Noooooooooo';}
```

My problem: In next refresh `$_SESSION['xxxc']` value gets changed.

Comment: Do you use `session_start();` at the beginning of each page? It is mandatory to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Use session_start(); at top of the page.

Comment: Yes I do but the problem is there

Comment: use ob_start(); before session_start();